# Why Passing { 5,7,5,8,1} as an array in method is throwing an Error in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

Thanks in advance. I am confused.

I have a method called reverseArray taking parameter as an array of integer. If I called in below way, it is not showing any error at compile time.(expected)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int input[] = { 5,7,5,8,1};
    int result[] = reverseArray({ 4, 6, 8, 9, 3 });
}
```

But while passing as below I am getting error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int result[] = reverseArray({ 5,7,5,8,1});
}
```

Can anyone help me to understand this?

Thanks

Comment: You didn't show the error, nor did you show the definition of `reverseArray`, please add this information. Thank you

Comment: The first code snippet will not compile, that's invalid Java syntax

Comment: you are passing array in the wrong way

Comment: I know that i have passed in wrong way. but if I can create an array in below format
`int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6); `
is correct.
But If I am passing  {1,2,3,4,5,6)  as an argument to method why it is giving me an error? I am curious about this

Comment: `reverseArray(new int[]{ 5,7,5,8,1});`

Comment: The first one does produce a compiler error: https://ideone.com/M1tgyV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a array as method reverseArray is expecting it as a argument.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int input[] = { 5,7,5,8,1};
  //Passing an anonymous array
  int result[] = reverseArray(new int[]{ 4, 6, 8, 9, 3 });
}
```

And if you want to pass arguments like the way you did you need to use let's say the `reverseArray method` is public static, so its signature needs to accept variable-length arguments.

```
public static int[] reverseArray(int... input){
//
}
```